# Connection over a proxy Quickfix/n

Tags: proxy, quickfixn

I am trying to establish a connection with quickfix/n but I am behind the company firewall. So I need to connect over a proxy to the acceptor.
According to the [documentation](https://quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html) of quickfix/j it is possible via JAVA, however in the [documentation](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html) of quickfix/n there is no information about possibility of connecting to the acceptor over a proxy via C#.

Is it possible at all to do that from C# with quickfix/n ?
In JAVA this can be done via configuration file, e.g.:

```
ProxyType=http
ProxyVersion=1.1
ProxyHost=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ProxyPort=YYYY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickFix/n v.1.7.0 does not support proxy at all.
QuickFix/n v.1.10.0 does support proxy (automatic via. WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()), however it does not support bypassing of the proxy details (user name and password).

I have created my own fork from v1.7.0 that supports user defined proxy (not WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy) + credentials. This can be found here: https://github.com/mcjacek/quickfixn

```
ProxyHost=proxy.intranet.yourproxy.com
ProxyPort=8080
ProxyUserName=UserName
ProxyUserNamePassword=Password
```

I will soon refactor and create PR to merge it to master.

Answer (score 0):

I had checked the below repo
https://github.com/mcjacek/quickfixn

In the code, the else block is not coded if suppose the username and password is not provided for the proxy host. Let us know if in the else block we need to send the request to the endpoint without the including the proxyMessage used for the authorization.

Comment: As a new user I recognize you don't have permission to comment yet. This sounds like good comment material. Maybe you could make an edit to add in the file and line numbers you're talking about as the codebase is large and last answer was posted several years ago?